# CSS not transitioning smoothly in and out of animation

Tags: css, css-animations

What's missing for the div to transition smoothly in and out of the pulse animation?

https://jsfiddle.net/86gxLy2a/

CSS

```
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transform: scale(.5);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from, to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.8);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delay the animation and scale up on hover

Update: Working smoothly in Chrome now as well. Only issue now is that the unpulse animation will run on page load.

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(.5);
  -o-transform: scale(.5);
  transform: scale(.5);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  animation: unpulse .3s;
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(.8);
    -o-transform: scale(.8);
    transform: scale(.8);
  }
}

@keyframes unpulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(.9);
    -ms-transform: scale(.9);
    -o-transform: scale(.9);
    transform: scale(.9);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(.5);
    -o-transform: scale(.5);
    transform: scale(.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, that's a really simple way of smoothing out the entry transition!  Any ideas for the exit transition?

Comment: Oh I was on Firefox which already had a smooth exit. This has to do with animations and transformations fighting over access to the elements. I'll test some in Chrome and see what can be done in this case though.

Comment: Updated for Chrome. The "unpulse" animation will run on page load though which probably isn't wanted. Depending on what you're trying to do though maybe it's fine. Alternatively could make the circle fade in on page load probably or something like that

Comment: That's still a _little_ awkward since the element has to unpulse even if midway through the pulse animation, but I think that's as close as we'll get with a pure CSS solution...   I ended up going for a solution which relied on transitions rather than animations (giving up the pulsing altogether) but with which I am satisfied at this point.  This was still enlightening though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your div's scale needs to be equal to the animations initial scale to appear smooth

transform: scale(1); - DIV

transform: scale(1); - Animation first keyframe

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;

  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from, to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(.8);
    -o-transform: scale(.8);
    transform: scale(.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>  
</div>
```